# Issues with synchronicity in JS fetch request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have page that is uploading multiple file to individual Google Signed URLs.

My `files_to_upload` variable is an array of file from my input. I then loop through these and call my `upload` function for each.

My `upload` function first fetches a signed URL generated from my own php script and then uploads the file to that URL.

When this happens I can see that the files are different the first time I log them but the last time I log them they are the same file which is the last one in the array.

Files get uploaded to separate URLs but the last file is uploaded to both of them.

There is definitely a synchronicity issue but I am unsure how to resolve this.

```js
for(var i=0; i<files_to_upload.length; i++){
  var this_file = files_to_upload[i];
  upload(this_file,options_selected,separation_type,user_id,);
}

function upload(this_file,options,separation_type,user_id){
  var new_file_name = encodeURI(this_file.name);
  new_file = new File([this_file], new_file_name, {type: this_file.type});
  
  console.log(new_file);
  
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('create', 'true');
  
  fetch('components/track_upload.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    var signedUrl = json['signedUrl']
    
    console.log(new_file);
    fetch(signedUrl, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: new_file
    })
    .then(response => response)
    .then((response) => {
      // do stuff
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: syncrhonousity in fetch? fetch is **a**synchronous

Comment: `then(response => response)` huh? `response.json()` or `response.text()` or something ... otherwise you can't `// do stuff`

Comment: You cant use sync fetch in javascript, if you want you can use "await"

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @YusufİlkerOğuz - which makes code *look* syncrhonous, even though it is still *asynchronous*

Comment: You realise all the uploads will begin at once with this code, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah thats kind of what i want, it works fine except for when there is multiple uploads in which case the last file gets uploaded to each url generated

Comment: not sure why that happens - try this code https://pastebin.com/SAmKzUdA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in an async IIFE but if you're in a function just make the function async

```
(async() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < files_to_upload.length; i++) {
        const this_file = files_to_upload[i];
        await upload(this_file, options_selected, separation_type, user_id, );
    }
})();
```

The upload function without async/await

```
function upload(this_file, options, separation_type, user_id) {
    const new_file_name = encodeURI(this_file.name);
    const new_file = new File([this_file], new_file_name, {
        type: this_file.type
    });

    console.log(new_file);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('create', 'true');

    return fetch('components/track_upload.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        var signedUrl = json['signedUrl'];
        console.log(new_file);
        return fetch(signedUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: new_file
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // do stuff
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

// or with async await

```
async function upload(this_file, options, separation_type, user_id) {
    const new_file_name = encodeURI(this_file.name);
    const new_file = new File([this_file], new_file_name, {
        type: this_file.type
    });
    console.log(new_file);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('create', 'true');
    try {
        const response = await fetch('components/track_upload.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        const json = await response.json();
        const signedUrl = json['signedUrl'];
        console.log(new_file);
        const response2 = await fetch(signedUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: new_file
        });
        const data = await response2.json();
        // do stuff with response data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```